# Ignore conflicts raised by setuptools install

Tags: python, setuptools, conflicting-libraries

### TL;DR

How can I instruct `setuptools` to ignore dependency conflicts and carry on normally?

### Background

My Python project has a set of Google Cloud dependencies declared in a `requirements.txt` file.
These Google Cloud dependencies have a transitive dependency conflict that is ultimately resolved and the application seems to function properly.

Executing `pip install -r requirements.txt` completes successfully and `pipdeptree` reports these conflicts, but `python setup.py install` fails due to these conflicts.

#### Warnings produced by `pipdeptree`

```
Warning!!! Possibly conflicting dependencies found:
* gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.3
- oauth2client [required: >=2.0.0,<4.0dev, installed: 4.0.0]
* google-gax==0.15.8
- oauth2client [required: >=2.0.0,<4.0dev, installed: 4.0.0]
* grpc-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.14.0
- oauth2client [required: >=2.0.0,<4.0dev, installed: 4.0.0]
* proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.3
- oauth2client [required: >=2.0.0,<4.0dev, installed: 4.0.0]
* grpc-google-iam-v1==0.11.1
- oauth2client [required: <4.0.0dev,>=2.0.0, installed: 4.0.0]
```

#### Errors produced by `python setup.py install`

```
error: oauth2client 4.0.0 is installed but oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0 is required by set(['proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1', 'gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1', 'google-gax'])
;
```

Comment: What does `transitive dependecy conflict` and how it can be `ultimately resolved`?

Comment: So the google cloud client libraries all depend on `oauth2client` - that's a transitive dependency. A dependency of a dependency. When a couple of dependency libraries all depend on different versions of another library - then it's a conflict.
 
pip can resolve these conflicts by automatically selecting one version out of all the required, and locks on to that.

Comment: Oh, okay. I've researched a little. Seems that pip is resolving dependency conflict by taking the first dependency that he would find. Seems that It's done so that the user could specify dependency in cli to override other dependencies. Which isn't acceptable in setup.py script. If setup.py has dependency conflict (and it isn't actually needed) then the authors should fix that. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Can't fix it myself in this case as it's a conflict between transitive dependencies of the Google libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. `setuptools` is strict in this way and conflicts must be resolved.